# Integrals- fundamental theorem of calucus

Tags: integration

If $g(1) = g'(1)=4$ and:

$f(x)=\int _0^x\:\left(x-t^2\right)g\left(t\right)dt$

What's $f''(1)$ ?

The theorem says: if $g(x) = \int _0^x\:f\left(t\right)dt$ then $g'(x) = f(x)$ But what would be $f(x)$ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $$f(x)=x\int_0^x g(t)\, dt - \int_0^x t^2g(t)\, dt$$ and therefore $$f'(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\, dt + xg(x) - x^2g(x) $$
Then $$f''(x)=g(x)+g(x)+xg'(x) - 2xg(x) - x^2g'(x) = (2-2x)g(x)+(x-x^2)g'(x)$$ and
$$f''(1)=(2-2\cdot 1)g(1)+(1-1^2)g'(1)=0$$

Comment: Thank you man but could you explain to me why what you did was wrong and how do you solve the first integral ( x* integral from 0 to x...)

Comment: It's derivative product rule: write $u(x)=x$ and $v(x)=\int_0^1 g(t)\, dt$. How do we derivate $u\cdot v$ ?